# Google Apps Script - call function deployed as API executable

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google apps script attached to a google sheet (where I have various methods manipulating the spreadsheet), and I have deployed it as API executable (enabling OAuth etc). Target is to  call those methods via REST from an external location not part of Google cloud (like an independent React client, or a standalone server, or my local machine)

Question is: How can I call this from a standalone javascript (like a node.js script executed on my local machine? I do have the script URL (script id) , the secret and the key, but don;t know how to use them all.
Could you help with some sample code, pointers, etc. It looks like my google searches hit only unrelated topics...

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [example](https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/guides/rest/api.html) on how to call the script as an API executable. You will see that the way to call the script from different languages is similar for example using `JavaScript`, you need to also take note on some important information like:

> The basic types in Apps Script are similar to the basic types in JavaScript: strings, arrays, objects, numbers and booleans. The Execution API can only take and return values corresponding to these basic types -- more complex Apps Script objects (like a Document or Sheet) cannot be passed by the API.

An example to make a call the way that you currently want using Apps script would be like:

`Target Script`

```
/** This is the Apps Script method these API examples will be calling.
 *
 *  It requires the following scope list, which must be used when authorizing
 *  the API:
 *    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
 */

/**
 * Return a list of sheet names in the Spreadsheet with the given ID.
 * @param {String} a Spreadsheet ID.
 * @return {Array} A list of sheet names.
 */
function getSheetNames(sheetId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  return sheets.map(function(sheet) {
    return sheet.getName();
  });
}
```

This is the script that you have setup as an API executable and you can call this script using `JavaScript` like this:

```
// ID of the script to call. Acquire this from the Apps Script editor,
// under Publish > Deploy as API executable.
var scriptId = "<ENTER_YOUR_SCRIPT_ID_HERE>";

// Initialize parameters for function call.
var sheetId = "<ENTER_ID_OF_SPREADSHEET_TO_EXAMINE_HERE>";

// Create execution request.
var request = {
    'function': 'getSheetNames',
    'parameters': [sheetId],
    'devMode': true   // Optional.
};

// Make the request.
var op = gapi.client.request({
    'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
    'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': request
});

// Log the results of the request.
op.execute(function(resp) {
  if (resp.error && resp.error.status) {
    // The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
    console.log('Error calling API: ' + JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
  } else if (resp.error) {
    // The API executed, but the script returned an error.
    var error = resp.error.details[0];
    console.log('Script error! Message: ' + error.errorMessage);
  } else {
    // Here, the function returns an array of strings.
    var sheetNames = resp.response.result;
    console.log('Sheet names in spreadsheet:');
    sheetNames.forEach(function(name){
      console.log(name);
    });
  }
});
```

Please note as well that there are some [limitations](https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/guides/rest/api.html#:%7E:text=calling%20API!%22%0Aend-,Limitations,-The%20Apps%20Script) that you may want to check before further perform tests.

Comment: Yes, seen this, but a) where do I get the gapi library from (npm, import, etc). There are many gapi* on npm; which one is used here? And b) how to use authentication with this? I need to pass a key and secret as well, not just the scriptId

Comment: I mean, for the library you can choose any of the available libraries from supported languages, you could use the [`Javascript`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/js) library for example, you can simply search for your preferred language and you would be able to find it as long as Google has one library for it. That specific example shows how to use the `client ID` and `API Key`

Comment: The "example" link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: As the script id, use the Apps Script project versioned deployment id instead of the Apps Script project id (script id).

---

I suggest you look at the official docs, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/. In the left panel, scroll down to Apps Script REST API. Expanding this section there is a Quickstarts subsection, including one quickstart for Node.js.

This week I faced a similar problem. In my case, I was trying to use the Apps Script API from the client side, in other words, from a webpage loaded using Google Chrome. I looked at the above-referred resources, but I used JavaScript quickstart. Since the components are the same, I think what I learned might be helpful to you too.

I posted the following self-answered question : [Problems with Google Apps Script API JavaScript "How to... Execute function"](https://software.codidact.com/posts/288780).

Briefly, when calling a Google Apps Script function / method using the Google Apps Script API,

1. When using development mode, `"devMode": true` use the script id.
2. In normal mode, `"devMode": false` or omitted, instead of the script id, use the Apps Script API deployment id.

To reproduce the problem, I have used the code from the Google Apps Script API Quickstart > JavaScript and How to... > Execute function, I just made some slight adjustments to make the `index.html` and the `index.js` files work together.

The `index.html` file loads the `index.js` file using an HTML script tag. Instead of calling the client-side function that creates a new Apps Script project, call the client-side function that calls the Apps Script function.

The call to the Apps Script function from client-side JavaScript looks as this:

```js
gapi.client.script.scripts.run({
    'scriptId': scriptId,
    'resource': {
      'function': 'getFoldersUnderRoot',
    }
```

As mentioned, the code given by Google works when adding `'devMode': true` to the `resource` property. To make it work using the versioned deployment instead of the head deployment, instead of assigning the Apps Script project id to the `scriptId` variable, assign the deployment id.